# Does CoreData/SQLite have something like database concept?

Tags: ios, core-data

I am planning to use Core Data framework in my i-Pad app. The use case here is that, there are multiple entities which holds group specific data of user and an user may part of multiple groups. When user log-in to a particular group he should only able to access that particular group specific data. In MySQL you can achieve this with the help of database in such a way one database for each group. Like that can I specify my core data framework(manged-object context) which database(something like that) to connect?. So that all further queries will return results for the specific group to which user has logged in.

Thanks,
durai.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

SQLite supports the "database concept", yes. Just create two SQLite files and you have two databases.

If you meant tables: a SQLite database does support tables.

You talk about "logging in" - you may want to avoid storing all the data on the client side.

Comment: Thank you Tom. Yes I understand and will not keep all the data in device.

Comment: It's worth mentioning that SQLite ≠ Core Data.